# How to enable CORS with Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, cors, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there a slick way to enable CORS with the Cloud Endpoints?

(Adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" or something like this to the response)

Thanks,
Brandon

Comment: I'd like to enable it for debugging on the client side too. :)

Comment: Is CORS not enabled by default for all domains? This may be a bug. If so I can file a bug on it internally.

Comment: I should mention it would be handy to be able to debug this locally, maybe modify the appengine-web.xml file. I've setup XHR2 request from my Dart editor but I need to turn on cors for it to work across domains locally too.

Comment: I found this but doesn't work.   <!-- appengine-web.xml -->
  <static-files>
    <include path="/*" >
      <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </include>
  </static-files>

Comment: Not sure about Cloud Endpoints, but I've managed to use the Cors filter for normal requests: http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/vosao-cms-development/cybFCgCvYt0

Comment: FYI I've filed a bug internally at Google to add CORS support to Endpoints.

Comment: I found out they support cors requests on the production server and a issue has been filed for the local debugging to support cors.

Comment: I put up a demo of it working: http://demogwtcloudendpoints.appspot.com

Comment: @Branflake2267 What did you end up doing? I don't see any difference in the endpoint classes and can't find an example of a GET CORS request in the code.

Answer (score 2):

As CORS works on production for Cloud Endpoints. What I did to test on devserver (local) was to disable the browser security. For Dartium (I think Chrome also) use --disable-web-security parameter on startup.

Comment: This is just what was looking for, send request to GAE on devserver

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the yaml file of your endpoint:

```
x-google-endpoints:
  - name: "{your-endpoint-host-name}"
    allowCors: "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on if you have control over the headers on the endpoints - either via the application or the web server serving the original page which contains scripts that want to make cross domain requests.

JSON-P still seems far more popular - either due to lack of support on the server side of platforms, or a distrust that it will work with clients (e.g. legacy web browsers) - whereas JSON-P will often work.

Comment: JSONP should work with Endpoints, but as usual only for GET requests.

Comment: yes, that is just one of the more one of the unpleasant things about it ;) I am surprised that CORS isn't more widely known, interested to see what other answers people have

Comment: I'd prefer to try enabling CORs by adding the response header to the endpoints responses. The question is how. :)

Comment: Branflake2267 - are you using python or java for GAE? if java, httpservletresponse or a filter can set the header, however, not sure if it will be ignored/not allowed by GAE

Comment: Java and in particular the new Java Cloud Endpoints api that has been released. I've added this to appengine-web.xml <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> but does not work on the reserved paths ./_ah*